# Ping-attack on a server?

Tags: security, ping, denial-of-service

Ok, following might be a stupid question but since I'm really new to hacking and cyber security stuff and I'm just thinking about how an attack on a website might look like, I'm gonna ask this:

What if you would use a very high amount of machines (for example a botnet) and run a ton of "ping" processes on them, all pinging one webserver at the same time, could this actually take down the server or massively interfere with its regular operation?

And is this already concidered a ddos attack, since I am trying to get the server down with a lot of "attackers"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. This type of attack is known as a "ping flood". From a [CloudFlare page about them](https://www.cloudflare.com/learning/ddos/ping-icmp-flood-ddos-attack/):

> **What is a Ping (ICMP) flood attack?**
>
> A ping flood is a [denial-of-service](https://www.cloudflare.com/learning/ddos/glossary/denial-of-service/) attack in which the attacker attempts to overwhelm a targeted device with ICMP echo-request packets, causing the target to become inaccessible to normal traffic. When the attack traffic comes from multiple devices, the attack becomes a [DDoS](https://www.cloudflare.com/learning/ddos/what-is-a-ddos-attack/) or distributed denial-of-service attack.

My impression is that these were one of the earliest types of DDoS attack, but have been mostly overtaken by more sophisticated types of attack, like [SYN floods](https://www.cloudflare.com/learning/ddos/syn-flood-ddos-attack/).

Answer (score 3):

It would probably not take down the server because answering a ping (technically, an ICMP Echo Request) consumes very little resources. But it could saturate the server's network connection, crowding out legitimate accesses and thereby effectively rendering it unreachable. And yes, that would qualify as a DDoS attack.